# Is it possible to run deploys in sequence (not in parallel) to target machine in the same Deployment Group in Azure Devops?

Tags: azure-devops, continuous-deployment, azure-devops-deploymentgroups

I use Azure Devops to deploy a web app to four server, that all should have the same configuration. My problem is that I would like to run the deploys in sequnce instead of doing it in parallel. This is because of load balencing so that deploys can be done fully automatically without any noticable downtime for the end users.

So I wonder if this can be done within the same Deployment group or do I need to split the target servers into multiple Deployment groups to achieve the?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When authoring an Azure Pipelines or Release pipeline, you can specify the deployment targets for a job using a deployment group. This makes it easy to define parallel execution of deployment tasks.

If you do not want it run in parallel, you could simply select **One target at a time** instead of using **Multiple** option of *Targets to deploy in parallel*.

[image]

It then will deploy to four server one by one instead of parallel. If you want a specific sequence of the four severs, it's not able to choose this. You may have  to split the target servers into multiple Deployment groups to achieve this.